# CI bus ID and GPU ID

Tags: nvidia, graphics, gpu

I have 3 graphics cards installed on Ubuntu 16.04, and when I checked the PCI bus IDs by using three different commands;

1. `nvidia-smi`,
2. `lspci | grep VGA`, and
3. `nvidia-settings`

1) and 2) gave the same IDs, but 3) gave different IDs.
It turned out that 3) was correct, which worked fine for another program while the others didn't. I was wondering why they gave different bus IDs in the first place.

Another problem was GPU IDs (0, 1, 2), where none of the GPU IDs reported were correct (commands 1)/2) and 3)), and I had to find the correct IDs by trying random combinations.
Below are the screenshots of a), b), and c).

[(a) nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOby3.jpg)
[(b) lspci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mgeo.png)
[(c-1) nvidia-settings_GPU0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLw1L.png)
[(c-2) nvidia-settings_GPU1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNCPv.png)
[(c-3) nvidia-settings_GPU2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7aQN.png)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It will be helpful if you run **a), b)** and **c)** in  your terminal. Then copy the output to clipboard and paste it into your question.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting. http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 2):

`nvidia-smi` and `lspci` display hexadecimal values.
`nvidia-settings` displays decimal values.

xorg.conf takes decimal values, that's why `nvidia-settings` seemed the correct one.